# How to stop try/except looping back to first input?

Tags: python, try-except

So I have the following code to catch user input errors:

```
while True:
     try:
        number1 = int(input('Number1: '))
        assert  0 < number1 < 10
        number2 = int(input('Number2: '))
        assert  0 < number2 < 10
        number3 = int(input('Number3: '))
        assert  0 < number3 < 10
        number4 = int(input('Number4: '))
        assert  0 < number4 < 10
    except (ValueError, AssertionError):
        print("Not valid")
    else:
        break
```

My problem is that if my user makes a mistake on entering number4 then the loop resets and they have to enter the first 3 numbers again. I would like instead to find a way to return to the number that they just entered incorrectly (preferably without using a while loop for each individual input).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extract the piece asking for a number:

```py
def input_number(message):
  while True:
    try:
      number = int(input(message))
      assert  0 < number < 10
    except (ValueError, AssertionError):
      print("Not valid")
    else:
      return number

number1 = input_number('Number1: ')
number2 = input_number('Number2: ')
number3 = input_number('Number3: ')
number4 = input_number('Number4: ')
```

A side note about `assert`: is best practice avoid to use of `assert` for cases like this because if you run python in optimized mode then they are stripped away, truth is that the optimized mode is usually not used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want individual handling for each input, then you need to write your code that way.  You wrote this as an all-or-nothing block.  The obvious way is to have individual blocks for each input.  The more usable way is to loop through your inputs and re-use a single `try-except`.

```
num_list = []
for i in range(4):
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input('Number ' + str(i) + ' : '))
            assert  0 < number1 < 10
        except (ValueError, AssertionError):
            print("Not valid")

        num_list.append(num)
```

Also see [loop until valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)